# how to use email notification after question is posted?

Tags: support, notifications, email

I posted a question and I'm interested in any potential answers (it seems like it might become a tumbleweed).  I saw the checkbox for "notify (email) daily of any new answers " - but how do I use it?  I already submitted the question, so I can't re-post the question, and I don't see an update button or anything to enable this notification feature.

Call me stupid, but how do I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you entered an e-mail address in your profile? Click on your profile and then "edit" to check/enter one.

If you have then you should see a check box followed by the words "Notify [email@example.com]  daily of any new answers" at the bottom of the page. You should be able to select this at any time after the question was posted.

When you enable the option you can edit the e-mail address to something else if you want.

Comment: Thanks - this was sortof a facepalm moment for me, the page must have saved it the same way up/down votes are saved.  I had checked the checkbox and changed the email to my work one (since it was an issue for work) and then I was expecting to confirm it somehow, like for comments/answers.

Comment: @weiji yeah, I think most people expect some sort of a confirmation. This bit of UI is not really done very well.

Comment: Is this checkbox still around? I don't see it. When did it go?