# How can I get email notification

Tags: discussion, email-notification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does StackExchange have email notification option?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122320/does-stackexchange-have-email-notification-option)
>   [How to get an email when I receive an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134760/how-to-get-an-email-when-i-receive-an-answer)

Other forums I have used can send me an email when I get an answer to a question so that I don't have to keep checking back all the time.  Is there a way to do that in this site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does StackExchange have email notification option?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122320/does-stackexchange-have-email-notification-option) and [how to use email notification after question is posted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24254/how-to-use-email-notification-after-question-is-posted).

Answer (score 4):

Click on "Stack Exchange" in the upper left corner, then click "Email Settings" in the lower left corner of the popup.

[image]

It can be set to email you new notifications (which would include new answers to your questions) as frequently as every 3 hours.

Comment: That looks to be much MORE than just answers to my posts.  "unread inbox notifications" could mean several different things.  Looks like it is not possible here on stack overflow to do this.  too bad.

Comment: @user1058647 Glancing through my own inbox, it appears to just be answers, comments, and chat messages.  If you're active in chat, I don't see why those would be annoying, and if not, you won't be getting any, so it would simply be answers and comments.  Not much more.

Answer (score 3):

I use StackGuru [StacksGuru: a near realtime bot for all Stack Exchange sites](https://stackapps.com/questions/345/stackguru-a-near-realtime-bot-for-all-stack-exchange-sites)  You can set it up to IM you if there is activity for a specific question (by question ID) or if there is activity on one of the tags that you are interested in.

Comment: That looks like just IM.  I need email notification.  I develop on my PC not on my phone so all my android related activities is on my phone.